# Cannot manually set the highlighted state of a UIButton in an IBAction method

Tags: swift, ios8, uibutton, ibaction, iboutlet

Inside my `ViewController`, I have two IBOutlets `signUpButton` and `memberButton`, and both buttons are linked to same `signUpOrMemberButtonPressed()` IBAction func. I am trying to set `highlighted` property to these 2 buttons so I can do subsequent work accordingly inside my `submitPressed()` IBAction func. But I noticed odd behavior between `signUpOrMemberButtonPressed()` and `submitPressed()` IBActions. After tapping on either `signUpButton` or `memberButton`, the button was highlighted inside my `signUpOrMemberButtonPressed()`, but by the time it executed `submitPressed()`, debug showed it's not highlighted. Here is my `signUpOrMemberButtonPressed()`:

```
@IBAction func signUpOrMemberButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    var button = sender as UIButton
    button.highlighted = true
    if signUpButton.highlighted {
        memberButton.highlighted = false
    } else {
        signUpButton.highlighted = false
    }

    if (signUpButton.highlighted) {
        println("signUpButton is highlighted inside 1st button")
    } else if (memberButton.highlighted) {
        println("memberButton is highlighted inside 1st button")
    } else {
        println("nothing is highlighted inside 1st button")
    }
}
```

My `submitPressed` function:

```
@IBAction func submitPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (signUpButton.highlighted) { println("signUpButton is highlighted inside 2st button") }
    else if (memberButton.highlighted) { println("memberButton is highlighted inside 2st button") }
    else { println("nothing is highlighted inside 2nd button")
}
```

When run my app, I tapped on `memberButton` and then tapped on submit button. Here is the log output:

```
memberButton is highlighted inside 1st button
nothing is highlighted inside 2nd button
```

Nothing was set to run between these two func calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening here is that the button is "un-highlighting" itself (after you manually set highlighted = true).

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIControl/highlighted) of the `highlighted` property:

> UIControl automatically sets and clears this state automatically when
>   a touch enters and exits during tracking and when there is a touch up.

You can set the highlighted state manually but you would have to do it after the UIButton unsets the highlighted state. You would have to do this on the next run loop which you can do by using `dispatch_async`.

The following should work:

```
var button = sender as UIButton
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.memberButton.highlighted = button == self.memberButton
    self.signUpButton.highlighted = button == self.signUpButton
}
```

Comment: Good to know this `highlighted` property's automatic unset behavior after user tap. I guess the automatic unset happens after `mysignUpOrMemberButtonPressed()`? I don't understand how exactly `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())` works... How does the code know by the time it tries to set `highlighted` property again in main queue this `highlighted` property was already automatically unset? Also why does the code not unset this same property automatically 2nd time within the `dispatch_async` block?

Comment: The `dispatch_async` call basically causes the code inside the `dispatch_async` call to be run after everything else has completed. If you put a breakpoint inside the `dispatch_async` call and one right after it, you  will see that the breakpoint that comes after gets hit first and then the one that is inside the `dispatch_async` call get hit afterwards.

Comment: See if the `selected` property of the button (instead of `highlighted`) will work for you. That's the property that actually should be used if you want to show that a button is in the selected state and you won't run into this issue. It will look slightly different visually so try it out.

Comment: I tried out your code. It worked out well. I changed my design to not use `highlighted` property just to avoid unpredicted things from happening, and added a bool for signUp or logIn for same functionality. This worked fine for me as well. Thanks for the explanations on `dispatch_async`